# get file content of google docs using google drive API v3 php in a variable

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api, drive

I am able to get file name of google doc using drive-api-php but I am unable to get file content in a php variable. provide me working code to get content of google doc file in a php variable. I checked api reference page but unable to understand how to use code. Not clear methos are given for php.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';



/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            echo '<a href="'.$authUrl.'">Log in here</a>';
            //print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = $_GET['code'];

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);


$fileId = "1jNCyWDaCq4KrUo3u3HolqQKysv2P5423KErpvHQNjn0";

$file = $service->files->get($fileId);
echo "File name: ".$file->getName();   //Working
echo "MIME type: " . $file->getMimeType(); //Working

$a = $service->files->getContent(); //Not Working provide code

echo "File Content: ".$a;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Get contents of a google doc using the google drive api.

Answer to your question is you cant.

You need to remember that the Google Drive api is a file storage api it can help you upload, download and list files stored in google drive.  It does not give you any access to edit the files stored with in Google drive.

## download file from google drive to your hard drive.

The file should be within the body but it depends upon the file type you are after if its a google doc then you will need to use file export and not file get.

Something like the following should export a google doc file to a microsof docx file and save it to your harddrive.

```
$file = $service->files->export($fileId, 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', array(
    'alt' => 'media' ));
$size = $file->getBody()->getSize();
if($size > 0) {
    $content = $file->getBody()->read($size);
}
```

## Edit the contents of a google drive document

In order to edit the contents of a google document you would need to use the [google Doc api](https://developers.google.com/docs/api).  Just remember the google doc api gives you the ability to edit the document programmatically.  If you want to be able to display the contents of google documents nicely on your website your going to have to do all the formatting and display yourself.

Comment: unable to get content either get() or export() method give me working coding example. I want get content of google doc.

Comment: can we be clear on what you mean by content?  You want to download the file and save it on your machine correct.    You do not want to be able to programticlly edit what is inside the file.

Comment: whatever written in google doc I want display it in browser using echo. Above code not working. Remember use google drive API v3 php.

Comment: Please see my edit. You are using the wrong api the google drive api does not have that capability